# The Strange Case of Missing Relationship Columns in Power Query (Data Source PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, powerquery

I have a PostgreSQL database with three tables and two 1-to-M relationships. When accessing the PostgreSQL table using Power Query, it would always show an additional column with the related table. I didn't realize why that column was there, but it was beneficial.

I had to delete and recreate two of the three tables. After that the "relationship column" as it is called in Power Query was missing. It was then when I realized that it is an Advanced option in Power Query to include the relationship column.

I am trying to get back the relationship column and made sure I granted all the permissions to user again, but until now I have not been able to get the relationship columns.

These are the relationships defined for the tables employee, department, and position.

```sql
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS saireco."position"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY ("EmployeeID")
    REFERENCES saireco.employee ("EmployeeID") MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS saireco."position"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY ("DepartmentID")
    REFERENCES saireco.organization ("DepartmentID") MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    NOT VALID;
```

This are the priviledges granted to user saireco.

```sql
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA saireco to saireco;
GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON SEQUENCE saireco."position_PositionID_seq" TO saireco;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE saireco.employee TO saireco;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE saireco.organization TO saireco;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE saireco."position" TO saireco;
```

Would the reason that the user does not have an relationship column in Power Query because the user has not been granted access to the relationship on the database? And if so, is there any way to confirm the in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was caused by not granting the REFERENCES privilege.

```sql
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE enworld TO saireco;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA saireco to saireco;
GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON SEQUENCE saireco."position_PositionID_seq" TO saireco;
GRANT SELECT, REFERENCES ON TABLE saireco.employee TO saireco;
GRANT SELECT, REFERENCES ON TABLE saireco.organization TO saireco;
GRANT SELECT, REFERENCES ON TABLE saireco."position" TO saireco;
```